# What does the percentage over a weapon mean?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-rift-apart

In the weapons menu, accessed by pressing the map button and switching tabs, each weapon has a percentage located above the weapon's level. What does this weapon percentage mean?

[image: weapon screen with a percentage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage over the weapon shows the measure of how close the weapon is to being fully upgraded. It is calculated by taking the total number of upgrades available for the weapon and dividing it by the number of upgrades that has been done or purchased.